# Regex in R (Invalid use of repetition operators) expression doesn't work after escaping

Tags: r, regex

I have a document with text like this that I'm trying to select a certain piece with regex:

> **Section I - Live Animals; Animal Products (Chapter 1-5)** Chapter 1 Live Animals

I'm using this expression, which works outside of R:

```
Section\s[A-Z]+\s?-\s[^(]*+\(Chapter\s[0-9]+-[0-9]+\)
```

This is how I've written the expression in R (have escaped the + after getting the Invalid use of repetition operators error), but the expression doesn't work - nothing happens. If anyone can see anything I'm missing here it would be much appreciated.

```
Section\\s[A-Z]\\+\\s?-\\s[^(]*\\+\\(Chapter\\s[0-9]+-[0-9]\\+\\)
```

I'm trying to select and remove the text like this:

```
df=data.frame(x="Section I - Live Animals; Animal Products (Chapter 1-5) Chapter 1 Live Animals ")
df=gsub("Section\\s[A-Z]\\+\\s?-\\s[^(]*\\+\\(Chapter\\s[0-9]+-[0-9]\\+\\)", "", df$x)
```

Comment: `*+` does not a valid regex make - pick one or the other. And don't escape anything besides the backslashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRE regex does not support [possessive quantifiers](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html), thus `*+` quantifier is not valid. You want `*` quantifier, thus, do not escape `+`, just remove it.

Also, it makes sense to trim the output, so I suggest using

```
df <- trimws(gsub("Section\\s[A-Z]+\\s?-\\s[^(]*\\(Chapter\\s[0-9]+-[0-9]+\\)", "", df$x))
## => [1] "Chapter 1 Live Animals"
```

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/DLLrSH).